# In a recursive function, how does a series of returns get assembled back into a single result?

Tags: scala, recursion

I'm trying to understand what's going on in this recursive function. It reverses a String, but I don't quite get how these separate return calls get assembled into one string at the end.

```
def reverse(string: String): String = {
    if (string.length() == 0)
      return string
    return reverse(string.substring(1)) + string.charAt(0)
  }
```

I've analysed the function by adding in print statement, and while I kind of understand how it works (conceptually), I don't understand, well... *how* it works.

For instance, I know that each cycle of recursion pushes things into the stack.

So, I would expect `reverse("hello")`, to become a stack of

```
o
l
l
e
h
```

But it must be more complex than that, as the recursive call is `return reverse(string.substring(1)) + string.charAt(0)`. So is the stack actually

```
o, 
l, o
l, lo
e, llo
H, ello
```

?

How does that get turned into the single string we expect?

Comment: why do you think that a `,` is being inserted there, run the code, learn to use a step debugger. print statements are the last bastion of the lazy ...

Comment: You're question will probably be closed. But I feel your pain. Recursion is hard to understand at first. @Jarrod Roberson is right, you should debug your code until you get it.

Comment: I wish to understand why people think this should be closed. It is a clear question, with an objective answer, directly related to programming.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I'm kind of glad it wasn't closed (again, I empathize with the OP). Still, I don't believe he *demonstrates a minimal understanding of the problem being solved* (but I do agree that "minimal" can be subjective). Btw, I also don't think he will grok recursion by reading your answer (or any other): at least in my experience, recursion is something you need to *see* to believe.

Comment: From Paul Graham's ANSI Common Lisp: "Students learning about recursion are sometimes encouraged to trace all the invocations of a recursive function on a piece of paper. [...] This exercise could be misleading: a programmer defining a recursive function usually does not think explicitly about the sequence of invocations that results from calling it." (page 42) "you don't have to think about all the invocations of a recursive function if you want to judge whether or not is correct. The same is true if you want to write a recursive function." (page 115). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stack contains all local variables, as well as any temporary result in an expression where the recursion appears (though those are pushed on the stack even without recursion, because JVM is a stack machine) and, of course, the point where the code execution should resume on return.

In this case, the recursive call is the whole expression (that is, nothing is computed before `reverse` on the expression it appears). So the only thing besides the code pointer is `string`. At the deepest level of recursion, the stack will look like this:

```
level    string
5        (empty string)
4        o
3        lo
2        llo
1        ello
0        hello
```

So when the call to level 5 returns, level 4 will finish computing the expression that `reverse` is a part of, `reverse(string.substring(1)) + string.charAt(0)`. The value of `reverse(string.substring(1))` is the empty string, and the value of `string.charAt(0)` is `o` (since the value of `string` on level 4 is `o`). The result is `o`, which is returned.

On level 3, it concatenates the return value from level 4 (`o`) with `string.charAt(0)` for `string` equal to `lo`, which is `l`, resulting in `ol`.

On level 2, it concatenates `ol` with `l`, giving `oll`.

Level 1 concatenates `oll` with `e`, returning `olle`.

Level 0, finally, concatenates `olle` with `h`, returning `olleh` to its caller.

On a final note, when a call is made, what is pushed into the stack is the return point for the code and the parameters. So `hello` is the parameter to `reverse`, which is pushed on the stack by `reverse`'s caller.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [substitution model](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1.5) to work through the problem:

```
reverse("hello") =
(reverse("ello") + 'h') =
((reverse("llo") + 'e') + 'h') =
(((reverse("lo") + 'l') + 'e') + 'h') =
((((reverse("o") + 'l') + 'l') + 'e') + 'h') =
(((((reverse("") + 'o') + 'l') + 'l') + 'e') + 'h') =
((((("" + 'o') + 'l') + 'l') + 'e') + 'h') =
(((("o" + 'l') + 'l') + 'e') + 'h') =
((("ol" + 'l') + 'e') + 'h') =
(("oll" + 'e') + 'h') =
("olle" + 'h') =
"olleh"
```

Comment: In general, if you find recursive thinking difficult, I recommend reading either "The Little Schemer" or "The structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs". The latter has been made available for free online by MIT Press.

Answer (score 0):

Аdd a couple of tips on how to make your code better:

1. Don't use return in functions because function automaticaly return result of last evaluated line
2. String is a List of Char's, and you can replace string.substring(1) => string.tai, and string.charAt(0) => string.head
3. If you call immutable method, like length, size or etc you can omit the parentheses string.length() === string.length

That last version of your single line function:

def reverse(s: String): String = if (s.size == 0) s else reverse(s.tail) + s.head